# TextField disappearing when tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

Using `Xcode 7.2.1`, I have set up some `textFields`. Certain times when I'm in the view controller, all `subviews` disappear from self.view when tapping a `textField`.

All constraints are satisfied, and I've even tried pinning them in numerous satisfying combinations with the same result.

When I look in the view debugger after this happens, all `subviews` of `self.view` are nowhere to be found.

I am very confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: can you please edit the question and provide full sourceCode of your viewController? so we can found if there is any logical error

Comment: @HitendraHckr Thanks for offering to help, however I was able to figure it out via my answer provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to deal with when I was calling popToRootViewController() in my logout viewcontroller that was presenting the (problematic) view controller.

All views disappeared in the view controller being segued to when popping before the segue:

```
  @IBAction func onLogoutTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    backendless.userService.logout({ (object) -> Void in
      self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("profileToLoginSegue", sender: self)
      }) { (fault) -> Void in
      print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    }
  }
```

However, when I called popToRootViewController() within the closure, the modally presented (and previously problematic) view controller acted normally:

```
  @IBAction func onLogoutTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    backendless.userService.logout({ (object) -> Void in
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("profileToLoginSegue", sender: self)
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
      }) { (fault) -> Void in
      print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    }
  }
```

I am not exactly sure why this is, but it was definitely the problem.